# How to keep a circle in his parent's bounds while I'm resizing it?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to resize a circle.To do that I bind a small circle that handle the resizing. How can i keep the dimension of the circle smaller then his parent (0,0) point simultaniously during the resizing?i could only get it work with width and height

```
if(this.getRadius() + deltaX + this.getCenterX() + handleRadius <= this.getParent().getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()
                           && this.getRadius() + deltaY + this.getCenterY() + handleRadius <= this.getParent().getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()

                            ){

                    this.setRadius(this.getRadius() + delta);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Solved :

```
 if(this.getRadius() + deltaX + this.getCenterX() + handleRadius <= this.getParent().getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()
                           && this.getRadius() + deltaY + this.getCenterY() + handleRadius <= this.getParent().getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()
                               && this.getCenterX() -this.getRadius() - handleRadius  - deltaX >= this.getParent().getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getMinX()
                                && this.getCenterY() - deltaY - this.getRadius() - handleRadius >= this.getParent().getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getMinY()
                            ){

                    this.setRadius(this.getRadius() + delta);
                }
```